# add only items which contains specific text in textbox

Tags: c#

```
string[] dirs = System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(@"C:\Somefolder\");

foreach (string dir in dirs)
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(Path.GetFileName(dir));
}
```

This is my code, and I have no idea how to get ONLY directories which contains name of something in my textbox for example. I have seen that someone had textbox, next to it button update, I tried to do it the same way - you write into textbox name of a folder ex. Windows and it shows ONLY the one folder so if I write Sys it will find System32 and SYSWOW64 && it wont be case sensitive cause I can do simple if condition, but cant make it not case sensitive you know what I mean? my english is pretty bad, had to tell it this way hope its understandable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably, you want this

```
string[] dirs = System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(@"C:\Somefolder\");
foreach (string dir in dirs.Where(x => x.Contains(textBox1.Text)))
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(Path.GetFileName(dir));
}
```

EDIT

```
string[] dirs = System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(@"C:\Somefolder\");
foreach (string dir in dirs.Where(x => x.ToLower().Contains(textBox1.Text.Trim().ToLower())))
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(Path.GetFileName(dir));
}
```

Comment: is there any way to do it this way but take even not case sensitive chars? i mean if there is folder "Windows" i want to list even if searching for "windows"

Comment: @yoloscope I have edit my post to ignore case sensitive search.